# JDK 1.6 Tomcat 6.0.53 cannot start inside Eclipse EE 2022-12

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, java-6

I am using JDK 1.6,
Error

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jdt/launching/internal/javaagent/Premain : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

If run standalone, success

[image]

[image]

if run debug inside Eclispe for Java EE 2022-12

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The needed classes are no longer compatible with Java 1.6, which in fairness ended free public updates close to a decade ago. The ["solution"](https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.debug/issues/61#issuecomment-1367165129) is to use an older IDE release.

Comment: Thank you very much! I experienced this thing, but not sure. I lost about 2.5 days for try to put my legacy tech stack web-app work with Eclipse 2022-12, but never success. But I don't know why until see your link from GitHub. I tried: Eclipse IDE for Java EE version 2022-06 can work with my tech stack (Spring 2.5.6 , JDK 1.6, Apache Tomcat 6, Windows 10 pro x64, jQuery 1.x - I need these things for maintain).

Comment: We should have a better error message, for example: Please use Eclipse lower version, since 2022-12, debug must use JDK 11, and attach this link to error message: https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.debug/issues/61

Answer (score 1):

I have the same kind of problem with a Java 6 application.

The eclipse is declared compatible from Java 1 to the last version (just go in the "Execution Environment" setting and you can see that all java versions are still supported) but it seems they have broken the compatibility without announcing anything.
This is very annoying but as I have seen until now, eclipse is very badly maintained and it's not the first time they break compatibility with some java library or some module.
Maybe the correct solution is to not use eclipse anymore and migrate to some other IDE as almost all my coworkers have done (IntelliJ seems to be the main choice today), I'm still on eclipse because I'm accustomed to it, but I shall consider the change.